# What are all comics about Emma Frost?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, suggested-order

I'm interested to know more about Emma, and I would like to know what does come after *Bloom's History*?

- *Emma Frost*: ***Higher Learning*** (*#1-6*)
- *Emma Frost*: ***Mind Games*** (*#1-6*)
- *Emma Frost*: ***Bloom*** (*#1-6*)

Updated:

I'm looking for part of her history when she became a Hellfire Club's dancer.

[Emma's Biography](http://x-men.wikia.com/wiki/Emma_Frost).

> Furious, she attacks Astrid telepathically and leaves her comatose. Though she is able to use her powers to save Ian's job, he rejects her when she confesses her powers as a mutant to him. **She becomes cold towards humans after this, and later auditions as a dancer for the Hellfire Club**

Comment: @Obie: Until recently Emma Frost was a villain and a secondary one at that. She didn't actually expand to becoming a real character until she became an X-man. And she barely maintained any qualities worth noting for quite some time. So any books you see her soloing in are rare and likely to remain limited series for the foreseeable future. 

To her credit she appears in lots of titles despite not having her own book. Check her entry on Wikipedia. She makes plenty of appearances in the Avengers and the AvX series.

Comment: What about X-Men Origins: Emma Frost? Where does take a place that history?